# XCode 4.0 general release

Tags: xcode4

XCode 4.0 is available for paid Apple devs. Does anyone know when (if ?) it will be available for general download for everyone to use ?

Comment: You should probably not be asking here if it's still under NDA.

Comment: He can ask whatever he wants, if he hasn't signed an NDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4 itself is not under NDA (see http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html). But as far as I know, there is no release date.